# what wrong with <h:commandButton value="...?userId=#{...}"

Tags: jsf

The whole syntax is as below

```
<h:commandLink action="CustomerDetails?faces-redirect=true&amp;customerId=#{item.id}" value="#{item.name}"/>
```

This is inside a dataTable, hence explain the use if `item`. But the above code give me

```
Not a Valid Method Expression: CustomerDetails?faces-redirect=true&customerId=#{item.id}
```

It seems to not allow me to concatenate string and EL expression. Done that many inside `value` attribute, must be something with the `action` attribute. Any one got a solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using an f:param in an h:link to set the customerId, which is the canonical way of setting query parameters.
So:

```
<h:link outcome="CustomerDetails" value="#{item.name}">
    <f:param name="customerId" value="#{item.id}" />
</h:link>
```

Comment: Nice, but I think it `action` should change to `outcome`. Dont think there is a action in h:link.

Comment: I should mention, the reason you're getting the error is that, when JSF sees an EL expression in h:commandLink's "action" attribute, it immediately assumes that you're passing it a Java method that returns an action string. That is, in the "action" attribute, you can't mix text with EL.

Comment: Sorry for being so picky, but I dont think faces-redirect=true is needed, since this is an explicit navigation, dont need to force a redirect here. PRG is not needed here.

Comment: mannn that is so correct. I knew that, but for some reason I did not think about it. Should be -1 for my question. So retarded. :( :(. +1 for point that out for me. Thank you